# how to retrieve checked values in php

Tags: php

I am a newbie in php.  I have a form with multiple checkbox values. I wanna retrieve the checked values and diplay these values on other php form.

Below is the code which works perfectly fine if we add the checkboxes without while loop.
But when added through while loop I am not able to fetch the selected items.

**xyzhtml.php**(html form)

```
<?PHP
        require ("DBConnect.php");
        $selectQuery =mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM fruits where approved = 0");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($selectQuery))
        {
          $fruit_name = $row['fruit_name'];
           echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"things[]\" value=\"$fruit_name\">";
           echo "<br>";
        }
        ?>

 On click of submit I call other php clled "xyz.php".
    Below is the code used in it.

 <?php

  $checkBox = $_POST['things'];

  echo $checkBox[0];
  for($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox); $i++){

  echo($checkBox[$i]);


  }

  ?>
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try use `var_dump($checkBox);` on your xyz.php after `$checkBox = $_POST['things'];` line and let see what the post contains.

Comment: Can you post here HTML code of your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things to check:

1. are you getting right values from the MySQL SELECT statement (check your HTML for empty checkboxes values and check your MySQL database for fruits that have approved field set to 0 to see if there are any)
2. when you don't tick a checkbox and submit the form, unticked checkboxes' values do not get submitted - have you thought about that?

Comment: @Smejko: Basically my things array appears to be empty. That means with the way I am doing the selected checkbook values are not getting added in the things array. MySQL SELECT statement is returning correct values.

Comment: try installing Firebug for Firefox - in the "Net" tab you will be able to see exactly what are you posting to the PHP file once you submit the form

Comment: also check that you have those checkboxes in a FORM element and that element points to the right PHP file

Comment: I placed the while loop to add the checkboxes in form element under the body tag but still it didn't work.

Comment: would you please tell me how to try install Firebug for Firefox. I have not done that before.

Comment: download Firefox - http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox, visit Firebug's website using Firefox: http://getfirebug.com, hit the "Install Firebug..." button, it will ask you to confirm installation - confirm that, wait until it finishes, restart Firefox, when Firefox runs again, on the lower right side of the status bar you'll see a little "bug" icon - click on it, Firebug will appear, click the last tab - "Net", it will give you option to enable that tab - do so, go to your page, submit form, see the net tab, unfold the first link that appears there, see "Params" tab in that link's information

Comment: @Smejko: It worked by adding the code for adding checkboxes in form element. Thanksssssssss a lot. :-)

Comment: cool, glad to help ;-)  btw: still, I'd recommend using Firebug in future to track down such issues - you would see that you're not posting any data in Firebug's output... and it's really useful in debugging JavaScript as well, should you get into that in the future ;-)

Comment: @smejko: Ya I found my mistake only by checking things in firebug. so in future i will definately keep using that. Thanx :-)

Comment: just a little side note :-D turn it off (it has a red Off button on the right side when it's shown) when you're not using it - sometimes, it slows down ordinary browsing and uses lots or memory if turned on for no reason ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to record $_POST['things']

```
if (!empty($_POST['things'])) {
   foreach ($_POST['things'] as $value) {
     echo "the value are: ".$value;
   }
}
```

Note: teh $_POST['things'] not $_POST['things[]']

Comment: good practise but doesn't solve the issue... there's nothing wrong with using a for loop

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work, but it *won't display anything if no checkboxes are selected*.

I would however remove the explicit `echo $checkbox[0]` (unless this is for testing purposes).

Try a `print_r($checkbox)` to see what's actually in that array.

Comment: Is this when the checkboxes are ticked or none are ticked?